# Xampp MySQL doesn't want a port

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

Literally, when i start the "mysql" server it doesn't have a port assigned(i know because in the mysql row in xampp in the port column there's nothing there) and when i try to acsess it in phpMyAdmin or through my website and even my vscode extension for databases(like the mysql workbench) its just says it refused to connect... Checking the mysql logs there's only some warnings:

```
2022-01-05T21:49:30.875196Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2022-01-05T21:49:30.875199Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.27) starting as process 6076
2022-01-05T21:49:30.950201Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-01-05T21:49:34.263390Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-01-05T21:49:36.583523Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011311] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'All I/O interfaces are disabled, X Protocol won't be accessible'
2022-01-05T21:49:37.927602Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2022-01-05T21:49:37.928600Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2022-01-05T21:49:37.933600Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-01-05T21:49:37.933601Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-01-05T21:49:38.112611Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: ''  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-01-05T21:49:48.764220Z 0 [System] [MY-013105] [Server] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.
2022-01-05T21:49:50.652328Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I'm using Windows 7 if that's important I'm not on my main computer(on vacation).
I've been trying to fix xampp issues for 1.5 days so any help appreciated.
**ALSO** i have installed mysql extension/addon or whatever because default mysql is actually MariaDB and I've figured it's why my queries didn't work so i followed a stack overflow awnser to install proper mysql(i was working with the mysqld --init stuff). **EDIT:** forgot to mention phpMyAdmin says invalid settings even tho i'm confident they are correct(i've tried everything i could find for that aswell).

Comment: Go to `C:\xampp` and find the file `properties.ini`. You should be able to check what is the port MySQL using. It's most probably the default `3306`.

Comment: Replying to FanoFN: That's true it was set to 3306 but changing it didn't seem to make a difference I restarted my computer and the mysql and apache servers started by themselves as well(not that changing the properties.ini did that just pointing out).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It was the mysql extension/add-on i installed. I reinstalled xampp and decided I was gonna deal with mariaDB.